# Match numbers with decimal separator inside a string

Tags: javascript, regex

This will match what i want:

```js
/\d+\.\d+/
```

and this will match it just in the start of the string:

```js
/^\d+\.\d+$/
```

and this for word boundary:

```js
/\b\d+\.\d+\b/
```

i want to match numbers like so:

```js
1.00000 // true
    1.0000 // true
1.0000     // true
bla1.0000 // true
1.0000bla // true
27.05.1989 // false (date)
```

Comment: Please state in the body of the question what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only achieve that with the help of the following regex:

```
(?:^|[^\d.])(\d+\.\d+)(?![.\d])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG0hD7/2)

```js
var re = /(?:^|[^\d.])(\d+\.\d+)(?![.\d])/gm; 
var str = '1.00000\n // true\n1.0000\n // true\nbla1.0000\n // true\n27.05.1989\n // false (date)';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

*Regex explanation*:

- `(?:^|[^\d.])` - match either the string start (`^`) or a character other than a digit and a literal dot
- `(\d+\.\d+)` - match and capture into Group #1 1 or more digits followed by a literal dot followed by 1 or more digits
- `(?![.\d])` - make sure there is no `.` or a digit after the float value

Comment: I have merged the last two lookaheads into one for better efficiency. The main problem is that there is no lookbehind in JS, thus, you have to rely on capturing and alternation mechanisms.